# LaTeX numbering?

Tags: latex

I have a problem with theorem numbering in [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). It numbers theorem 1 from section 1 as theorem 11 instead of theorem 1.1.

How do I make it work?

Comment: It would probably help if you'd show your LaTeX script, or at least the part responsible for the numbering.

Comment: Presumably you (or something) is redefining `\thetheorem` incorrectly. las3rjock's answer below should probably help fix the problem.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using the theorem environment from the [AMS-LaTeX](http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex.html) package, putting the following code in the preamble of your document should work:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
```

Here is a sample document and its output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document}

\section{Lorem}

\begin{theorem}
Ipsum
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[Sample output http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8938/theorem.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8938/theorem.png)